# Core Motion Pedometer Save Timer Data when in Background

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, core-motion, pedometer

I've started to play with the Pedometer and it's working just fine. I've made a timmer that will show me the working out time and it's working perfectly tracking the Activity Type. The Pedometer will update in the background automatically, however, the timmer will not. I know I have to use a Notification for applicationDidEnterBackground. I can find out how much time elapsed since the app went into the background till now so I can make the difference in time.

My problem is: How would I know how much of that time is WALKING & RUNNING?
Because it's going to give the time for all Events. Does anybody know a solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem. Each time this function is triggered it means the user has activity:

```
//START GETTING UPDATES
private func startUpdating() {
    if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
        startTrackingActivityType()
    }

    if CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable() {
        startCountingSteps()
    }
}
```

In this function startCountingSteps(), I placed an array that will append one item each time it's triggered if steps count is bigger than 1, for each second. Meaning it's either Walking or Running.

I saved the time in seconds when the user enters background and get the current time when the user opens up the app again. The current number of seconds + array.count = Current elapsed working out time.